# External application dashboard in Banno

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

We created a custom application and linked it to the dashboard. The UI is loading inside the dashboard in Mobile App but not loading in Edge/Chrome. In the browser, UI is loading after clicking the primary action button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern web browsers have become increasingly restrictive about how content is handled from secure contexts (i.e., *https*) and unsecure contexts (i.e., *http*) and generally doesn't like to mix the two.

Banno Online is served up in an https context so all of the content (including plugins) should be served up with https as well.

The only exception to that general rule is *localhost* (e.g., for local development such as the [Simple Plugin Example](https://github.com/Banno/simple-plugin-example/blob/main/server.js#L50)).

It's worthwhile to read up on these pages for the Plugin Framework:

- [Restrictions](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/restrictions/)
- [Authentication](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/overview/authentication/)